# Best approach to solve this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm lost. I tried u-substitution and integration by parts, and ended up with nothing good.

By parts just repeats itself over and over again. What should I do?

$$\int(e^{-t}+3e^{-t}\sin(t))dt$$

The first integral is easy. It's the 2nd one I don't get. Doing by parts:

$u = e^{-t}$

$du = -e^{-t}$

$dv = \sin(t) dt$

$v = -\cos(t)$

$$uv - \int vdu = -e^{-t}\cos(t) - \int(\cos(t)e^{-t})dt$$

So, is this integral impossible to solve?

Comment: the second integral is cyclic. Integrate by parts again and collect terms.

Comment: You should try look up an example of integration by part involving trignometric functions. There is also a crazy method involving a table so called tabular method, you need three rows, but it is very risky to use and fairly non-rigorous - sadly that is the only one I use for most back of the envelope calculations.

Comment: I got $\frac{e^{-t}cost}{2} - \frac{e^{-t}sint}{2}$  you da man @Chilango

Comment: Could write $\sin(t)=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$ to get another two easy integrals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying to be more general, for the computation of $$I=\int e^{-at}\cos(bt)\,dt$$ let us also consider  $$J=\int e^{-at}\sin(bt)\,dt$$ So, $$I+i J=\int e^{-at}\Big(\cos(bt)+i\sin(bt)\Big)\,dt=\int e^{-at} e^{ibt}\,dt=\int e^{-(a-ib)t} \,dt=\frac{e^{ -(a-i b)t}}{-a+i b}$$ Now, computing the real and imaginary parts of the last expression, we then get $$I=\frac{e^{-a t} (b \sin (b t)-a \cos (b t))}{a^2+b^2}$$ $$J=-\frac{e^{-a t} (a \sin (b t)+b \cos (b t))}{a^2+b^2}$$

Comment: Very nice answer Monsieur Claude. +1

Comment: @LeoSera. Thank you ! But this is just a very simple and traditional trick. I am too lazy for two integrations by parts.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but I don't follow this step:  $\Big(\cos(bt)+i\sin(bt)\Big) = e^{ibt}$  Is this some identity?

Comment: This is Euler formula $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$. For sure, if you did not learn it already, my answer is totally off-topic.

Comment: THis is awesome; thank you @ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 2):

There are of course several ways of calculating the integrals
$$I=\int e^{-at}\cos(bt)\,dt$$
and
$$J=\int e^{-at}\sin(bt)\,dt.$$

@Claude Leibovici mentions one nice way in his answer and @Chilango and @A.G. two others in comments. I give this answer just for funt and just to show another way, that I think is less known. I think this site is a nice place to show such things. I don't claim it is easier. I actually think that it is conceptually more difficult but once known, the calculations are very simple.

> ***Warning***
>
> Don't use this method if you do not understand how it works and what you are allowed to do, since it will otherwise (just as other methods) don't work. Also, I don't claim my derivation to be totally rigorous. I suggest to get a copy of some ODE book where it is present.

I show the method for $J$ (since this is the one appearing in the question) and leave it to others to do $I$. We want to solve $DJ=e^{-at}\sin(bt)$, where $D$ is the differential operator. This can, formally, be written
$$
J=D^{-1}e^{-at}\sin(bt).
$$
The idea is to commute $D^{-1}$ and $e^{-at}$:
$$
D^{-1}e^{-at}f(t)=e^{-at}(D-a)^{-1}f(t).
$$
Small check: Taking derivatives on both sides:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{LHS:} \quad DD^{-1}e^{-at}f(t)&=e^{-at}f(t)\\
\text{RHS:} \quad De^{-at}(D-a)^{-1}f(t)&=-ae^{-at}(D-a)^{-1}f(t)+e^{-at}D(D-a)^{-1}f(t)\\
&=e^{-at}(D-a)(D-a)^{-1}f(t)\\
&=e^{-at}f(t).
\end{aligned}
$$

We find that
$$
J=e^{-at}(D-a)^{-1}\sin(b t).
$$
Inserting $(D+a)(D+a)^{-1}$, and using $(D+a)^{-1}(D-a)^{-1}=(D^2-a^2)^{-1}$, we get
$$
J=e^{-at}(D+a)(D+a)^{-1}(D-a)^{-1}\sin(bt)=e^{-at}(D+a)(D^2-a^2)^{-1}\sin(bt).
$$
Now, $D^2\sin(bt)=-b^2\sin(bt)$, so $(D^2-a^2)^{-1}\sin(bt)=(-b^2-a^2)^{-1}\sin(bt)$, and $(-b^2-a^2)^{-1}$ is just a number and can be moved to the left. Hence
$$
J=e^{-at}(D+a)(-b^2-a^2)^{-1}\sin(bt)=-\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}e^{-at}(D+a)\sin(bt).
$$
Finally, we note that $(D+a)\sin(bt)=b\cos(bt)+a\sin(bt)$, so
$$
J=-\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}e^{-at}\bigl(b\cos(bt)+a\sin(bt)\bigr).
$$
This all became rather long to describe, but here goes the calculation in the particular example:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int e^{-t}\sin t\,dt &= D^{-1}e^{-t}\sin t=e^{-t}(D-1)^{-1}\sin t\\
&=e^{-t}(D+1)(D^2-1^2)^{-1}\sin t=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}(D+1)\sin t\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}\bigl(\cos t+\sin t\bigr).
\end{aligned}
$$

> ***Small challenge to the ones who read all through:***
>
> Try to adapt this method to calculate $\int t^2e^{-t}\,dt$?

Answer (score 1):

$  let.    I=\int e^{-t} (\ sin t)   dt$

> $Here.   u=\sin t , v=e^{-t}$

$\implies I= \sin t  \int e^{-t} dt -\int [{\frac{d}{dx}(\ sin t ){\int e^{-t}dt}}] dt$

$\implies I={\sin t}[\frac{e^{-t}}{-1}]+\int \cos t e^{-t}dt$

$\implies I={\sin t}[\frac{e^{-t}}{-1}]+\cos t \int e^{-t}dt -\int[\frac{d}{dx}(\ cost )\int e^{-t}dt]dt$

$\implies I=-{e^{-t}}(\sin t )-(\cos t ) e^{-t} -\int[(-\sin t )(- e^{-t})]dt$

$\implies I=-{e^{-t}}(\sin t )-(\cos t ) e^{-t} -I$

$\implies 2I=-{e^{-t}}[\sin t +\cos t ]$

$\implies I=\frac{-{e^{-t}}}{2}[\sin t +\cos t ]$----->(1)

Now

$\int[ e^{-t}+3 e^{-t}\ sin t ] dt= \int e^{-t}dt+3\int e^{-t}\sin t dt$

From eq(1)

$\int[ e^{-t}+3 e^{-t}\ sin t ] dt= -e^{-t}-\frac{3e^{-t}}{2}[\sin t+\cos t]$

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer but too long for a comment): Note that you can use Maple to suggest solution for you (but it is questionable how simple the suggested solution really is), in this case:

```
Student[Calculus1][IntTutor](exp(-t)+3*exp(-t)*sin(t),t);
```

Ouput:
[image]